# Remove accents while comparing excel files using python

Tags: python, excel, pandas

i want to compare two excel files and delete rows with common names in the second file. the issue is that one list doesn't have accents while one does. i want to remove the accents in order to compare the names, delete from the second file and then merge the two files. thanks!

code so far

```
import pandas as pd
from unidecode import unidecode

df0 = pd.ExcelFile('Players.xlsx').parse('Sheet1')
df1 = pd.ExcelFile('Players.xlsx').parse('Sheet1')

result = df0[df0[(unidecode('Name'))].isin(df1[unidecode('Name')])]
result.to_excel('Merged.xlsx', index=False)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the best way to remove accents in a Python unicode string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/517923/what-is-the-best-way-to-remove-accents-in-a-python-unicode-string)

Comment: not really because it seems like unidecode only works with a string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed in the comments by Corentin, you want to remove accents from your second excel file.

```
from unidecode import unidecode
df1["Name"] = df1["Name"].apply(unidecode)  # strip accents from Name column
result = df1[~df1["Name"].str.isin(df0["Name"].unique())]  # keep only if name not in df0
```

Please note that:
- The `~` operator is equivalent to a NOT boolean operator.
- using `df0.Name.unique()` enables to lookup only on unique (i.e. distinct) name values in `df0`.

Comment: i keep getting the error ```AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'Name'``` even if i try to define the name column of df1

Comment: Oh, you should check your column names then. Is it really `Name` for both? 
Check by using `print(df0.columns, df1.columns)`. I guess the logic is right, just need to make sure your columns are properly named.

Comment: the columns are actually Player Names, which would obviously give syntax errors for the result line due to the space. do you know the correct way to write it out?

Comment: Yea sure, avoid using `df.ColumnName` but instead use `df["ColumnName"]` which won't get you into troubles when there is a space. Hence, use `df["Player Names"]`. Also edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can normalize strings with accents using `unicodedata.normalize`

Code:

```py
import unicodedata
my_str = 'àbćdë'
str(unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', s).encode('ascii', 'ignore'), 'utf-8')
```

Output:

```
'abcde'
```

To apply to a DataFrame use:

```py
def normalize(s):
    return str(unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', s).encode('ascii', 'ignore'), 'utf-8')

df1.Name.apply(normalize)
```